# Verifying Deployment: FAILED on deploying Telescope App

Tags: meteor, deployment, telescope

I'm trying to deploy the TelescopeApp to DigitalOcean, using mup. All seems to be going well until the 'Verifying Deployment: FAILED'. I am using the abernix/meteord:base dockerimage.

The error reads "Failed at the v8-profiler@5.6.5 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'. Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed. If you do, this is most likely a problem with the v8-profiler package, not with npm itself."
The entire error is here http://pastebin.com/4pDHy5KM

I tried to install Telescope on another DigitalOcean droplet, and deploy it from there, but got the same error when deploying to the Telescope droplet. Any ideas on how to fix this?

mup.js:

```
module.exports = {
 servers: {
  one: {
   host: 'x.x.x.x',
   username: 'root'
  }
 },
 meteor: {
  name: 'Telescope',
  path: '.',
  servers: {
   one: {}
  },
  buildOptions: {
   serverOnly: true,
  },
  env: {
   ROOT_URL: 'http://x.x.x.x',
  },
  dockerImage: 'abernix/meteord:base',
  deployCheckWaitTime: 60
 },
 mongo: {
  oplog: true,
  port: 27017,
  servers: {
   one: {},
  },
 },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

On the slack channel of the TelescopeApp I was told to disable nova:kadira
and to run mup with the --settings flag to be sure. This solved the deployment problem.